# Call to a member function get_posts() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeIgniter. I have the problem saying that Fatal error: Call to a member function get_posts() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_series_5\application\controllers\posts.php on line 12

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->model('post');

    }

    function index(){
        $data['posts']=$this->post->get_posts();         line 12
        $this->load->view('post_index',$data);
    }
```

Post.php in model is below

```
class Post extends CI_Model{

    function get_posts($num=20,$start=0){           
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')
        ->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added', 'desc')
        ->limit($num,$start);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    function get_post($postID){
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where(array('active'=>1,
        'postID'=>$postID))->order_by('date_added','desc');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->first_row('array');
    }
```

Comment: do you have `get_posts()` function in your post model ?

Comment: yes i have that function in post.php in model folder

Comment: I think it is because of you returning result_array()

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding `_model` in your model name. `post_model.php`

```
<?php
class Post_Model extends CI_Model {
  public function get_posts() {
   // code here
  }
}
```

And in your controller,

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    public function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->model('post_model');

    }

    public function index(){
        $data['posts']=$this->post_model->get_posts();         
        $this->load->view('post_index',$data);
    }
```

Comment: Hi devo thanks for your reply but again i am getting the same error my code for post.php<?php

 class Post_Model extends CI_Model{
 
  function get_posts($num=20,$start=0){   
   $this->db->select()->from('posts')
   ->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added', 'desc')
   ->limit($num,$start);
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();
  }
  
  function get_post($postID){
   $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where(array('active'=>1,
   'postID'=>$postID))->order_by('date_added','desc');
   $query=$this->db->get();
   return $query->first_row('array');
  }

Comment: Do you have file ``post_model.php`` in your ``application/models`` folder with ``get_posts`` function?

Comment: I you are in linux, try to add permission.

Comment: devo can you help me to add permission i dnt know how to add

Comment: Goto terminal by ``ctrl+alt+T`` and type ``sudo chmod 777 -R your_path``. Here my path is like ``/var/www/ci_project``

Comment: If you are in lamp, it will be ``sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/``

Comment: Your model name should be ``post_model.php`` and not ``post.php``

Comment: ya i will change and save that

Answer (score -1):

if want to fetch data from any form, then your code should be :

```
$data['posts']=$this->post->('field_name')


<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>/posts" method="post">
<input type="text" name="field_name">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Totally wrong answer problem is of loading model not to get posted data